# $\bar A$ is Perfecly Normal Lindelöf implies that $A$ is Lindelöf

Tags: general-topology

I would like to show that $\bar A$ is Perfectly Normal Lindelöf implies that $A$ is Lindelöf. I don't know what to try, I tried to pick a open cover of $A$ and to transfer it somehow to $\bar A$ but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure is irrelevant: if $X$ is perfectly normal and Lindelöf then all subspaces of $X$ are Lindelöf. This follows because all open subspaces of $X$ are $F_\sigma$ (taking complements and using that closed sets are $G_\delta$.). And an $F_\sigma$ subset of a Lindelöf space is again Lindelöf (obvious for closed subsets, and countable unions of countable subcovers are still countable subcovers). So open subset of $X$ are Lindelöf.

If now $A$ is any subspace of $X$, taking an open cover of $A$ by relatively open subsets $O_i, i \in I$, find $U_i$ open in $X$ with $U_i \cap A = O_i$. Then $U = \cup_{i \in I} U_i$ is open and is covered by the $U_i$, so has a countable subcover (with the same union $U$) which then gives a countable subcover of the $O_i$. So $A$ is Lindelöf.